# Can't find the error in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, debugging

This js program should display the first 100 prime numbers, but instead it crashes each and every time and I can't find the error! Could someone point me towards the best way to debug js code?! Thank you!

```
// initialisation of the array p holding the first 100 prime numbers
var p = [];

// set the first prime number to 2
p.push(2);

// find the first 100 prime numbers and place them in the array p
var i = 3;
while (p.length < 100) {
    var prime = true;
    loop:
    for (var item in p){
        if (i%item === 0){
            prime = false;
            break loop;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        p.push(i);
    i = i + 2;
}

// display the first 100 prime numbers found
var i=1;
for (var item in p){
    document.writeln(i,item);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Use your browser's debugger? Put in some `console.log()` statements to double-check your expectations? Use paper and pen(cil) to step through the code?

Comment: Avoid use label statements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label
You can just use break;

Comment: `for (var item in p)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for (var item in p) {
```

to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    item = p[i];
```

`for-in` iterates over the keys of an object or array, not the values.

Comment: "for-in iterates over the keys of an object or array, not the values" was indeed the problem! Thank you, Barmar.

Answer (score 2):

First, put your algorithm in to a funciton and put this function into a page html. like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function test(){
// initialisation of the array p holding the first 100 prime numbers
var p = [];

// set the first prime number to 2
p.push(2);

// find the first 100 prime numbers and place them in the array p
var i = 3;
while (p.length < 100) {
    var prime = true;
    loop:
    for (var item in p){
        if (i%item === 0){
            prime = false;
            break loop;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        p.push(i);
    i = i + 2;
}

// display the first 100 prime numbers found
var i=1;
for (var item in p){
    document.writeln(i,item);
    i++;
}
}

</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <a onmouseclick="test()">test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

then open this page in Chrome or firefox.

press F12 to open the debug panel.
then go to Sources tag dans choose your page (for exemple: test.html) in the left view and make a stop point debug on the line `var p =[];`then click the link test on the page to begin your debug. F10 to go to another line and F11 to enter method, F8 to go to next stop point.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```js
if (i%item === 0){
```

to

```js
if (i % p[item] == 0){
```

then it will work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDEKv/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the final working code looks like:

```
// initialisation of the array p holding the first 100 prime numbers
var p = [];

// set the first prime number to 2
p.push(2);

// find the first 100 prime numbers and place them in the array p
var i = 3;
var item;
var prime;
while (p.length < 100) {
    prime = true;
    for (item in p){
        if (i%p[item] === 0){
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        p.push(i);
    i = i + 2;
}

// display the first 100 prime numbers found
var s = "";
for (item in p){
    if (item != p.length - 1){
        s = s + p[item] + ",";
    }
    else{
        s = s + p[item];
    }
}
alert(s);
```